# rsErrorLoadingCodeModule: what are the steps to deploy an assembly for use with Report Builder 2.0?

Tags: reporting-services

I've built an assembly with a `public static` class and a `public static` method with a return type of `int`. Eventually I'll add more methods but for now the assembly contains just one method. I'm trying to use this assembly in my SSRS reports but it results in an error:

> [rsErrorLoadingCodeModule]
>   Error while loading code module: ‘XXX.Calcs, Version=2013.1.21.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null’.
>   Details: Could not load file or assembly 'XXX.Calcs, Version=2013.1.21.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I referenced the assembly through `Report Properties` -> `References`. When I create an expression that uses the method in the assembly and then build, I get the above error.

I deployed the assembly to:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
```

Thoughts? Am I missing any steps?

Comment: Are you using this locally or are you testing against a Report Server?

Comment: At this point, I'm building a report in VS2008.

Comment: What happens when you add the DLL to Windows\assembly as well?

Comment: Also, another thing I remembered... It may be a silly question, but have you restarted VS? I seem to remember it only loaded assemblies for reports when the application is started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dknight/2012/01/26/ssrs-custom-code-with-external-assemblies/) and followed the steps exactly.

Comment: I spent hours on this a couple months ago trying to get it to work with no luck.  This link finally helped me figure it out, thank you!!!!!!!  I think the only thing I missed was that .NET has to be set to version 2.  I'm relieved that I can use custom assemblies again in Sharepoint Integrated mode!  Thanks!