# Report Builder custom method of assembly returns "#Error"

Tags: methods, reference, report, .net-assembly, builder

I am currently trying to add an assembly into report builder 3.0 to execute a method and return the result:

But I always get "#Error" in the preview. Even whe the method is that simple:

```
public static string Test()
    {
        return "test";
    }
```

Reference is set the following:
[image: assembly reference in report builder]

Expression is:

```
=TestNamespace.TestClass.Test()
```

The assembly is registered in GAC and it seems that the method is being checked for availableness. Elsewise I get a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it.

Important is to set the following into AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
using System.Security;
[...]
// added to use in Reporting Services
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers()]
```

More info:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dknight/2012/01/26/ssrs-custom-code-with-external-assemblies/
[rsErrorLoadingCodeModule: what are the steps to deploy an assembly for use with Report Builder 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486161/rserrorloadingcodemodule-what-are-the-steps-to-deploy-an-assembly-for-use-with)

It is also not required to put the Assembly file in GAC. I simply put it here to test it locally:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Report Builder 3.0
```