# SSRS Report Builder How to parse JSON from Dataset field?

Tags: .net, json, reporting-services, json.net, ssrs-2012

I am creating a report in Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 3.0 running on Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 11.0.2100.60.

I would like to parse JSON values stored in some of the fields from my DataSet. Below is a preview of my report showing raw JSON values.

[image]

The expression I expected (though not being added) would be something like below,

```
=Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(Fields!MyFieldName.Value).ToString()
```

Since I need to [add custom or embedded code to my report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx) to be called from any expression, I have to [add an Assembly Reference to a Report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155974.aspx). Ref: [Using Custom Assemblies with Reports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153561.aspx)

So in my report properties, a reference to Json.net (Newtonsoft.Json.4.5.6) assembly has been added as described below.

[image]

The path to the assembly is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Packages\Newtonsoft.Json.4.5.6\lib\net40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll`.

I have also tried adding the assembly to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\` as well as `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.SQL2008\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\` and changing the reference to the path but to no avail.

It is also mentioned that [the assembly has no dependency](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/4.5.6).

So far, I have just added the assembly reference and nothing whatsoever has been changed. However, once I switch to preview my report, the error shows as described below:

[image]

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Error while loading code module: ‘Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.CreateReportEditSession(String Report, String Parent, Byte[] Definition, String& EditSessionID, Warning[]& Warnings)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.CreateReportEditSession(String Report, String Parent, Byte[] Definition, String& EditSessionID, Warning[]& Warnings)
```

Is it because of the lack of permission attribute `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers()` in the assembly? According to a reference [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dknight/2012/01/26/ssrs-custom-code-with-external-assemblies/) which does not solve my issue since the assembly in my case is not custom built, and neither could another question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943653/report-builder-custom-method-of-assembly-returns-error) and a tutorial [here](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s291/custom-assembly.htm).

What am I doing wrong? Or is there any working example for parsing JSON in SSRS report?

Any help would be of great assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I am possibly over simplifying here but is the assembly ddl located on the Client the report server or both, as I have found in the past unless I have assemblies on both client and server I get odd error messages. Also after adding the ddl to the bin directory mine is as follows (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin) the report server service needs to be restated to pick up the assembly

Comment: Anyone solved this issue? I have come across similar issue

Answer (score 0):

The error states it can find `Version 4.5.0.0`; the image you showed is for `Version 4.5.6` These are not interchangeable, unless explicitly specified so.

So you have two options:

1. Remove the current reference to NewtonSoft.Json.dll; clear your folder(s) from all the versions of that DLL and start over.
2. Specify an `assemblyBinding` at machine level - `machine.config`. Here's how you do it [< assemblyBinding > Element for < runtime >](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twy1dw1e(v=vs.110).aspx). Focus on the first example. The `bindingRedirect` is what you looking for.