# SSRS 2008 R2 Missing reference to System.Numerics

Tags: reporting-services, .net-assembly, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report that I wrote, taking advantage of System.Numerics.BigInteger. When the client installs the report they get this error:

[image]

The client is using .NET version 4.6.1 and the report works when installed on my local server. When I wrote the report I had to add a reference to the assembly like so:

[image]

What am I missing/not understanding that causes this not to work?

Comment: Have you tried these SO answers[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14566823/3266499), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992373/reporting-services-2012-deploy-error-error-while-loading-code-module)

Comment: Look at what you've done and the make a guess. As you are a report developer with at least one client, I trust in that you can find the answer yourself. If not, then imagine that you are your client's Report Server.